# Ejecutar dos funciones distintas

Tags: php, funciones

me encuentro ante la necesidad de ejecutar dos funciones distintas, una de ella lleva un href que es donde saco el ID de una tabla de mysql y la otra funcion es la que elimina dicho registro. No se mucho de php la verdad y este codigo lo e sacado mirando por internet y editando un poco. mi pregunta es... ¿como puedo llamar a la funcion en el href y que este actue como un boton, si la funcion la otra es disinta?

De igual forma dejo mi codigo por si alguien me puede ayudar.

PD: no quiero ejecutar la funcion de elimnar en otro archivo, deseo hacerlo de esta manera.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias ORDER BY id ASC ";
        $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) 
        {
        ?>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['autor']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['categoria']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['update']; ?></td>
          <td><a href="#">Editar</a></td>
          <td><a href="./elim.php?id=<?php echo $row ['id']; ?>">Eliminar</a></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
    <?php
        }
        ?>
</table>
<?php 

}

function eliminar_noticia($conexion){
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $sql = "DELETE FROM noticias WHERE id = '$id'";
        $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

        if ($resultado) {

         echo "El registro fue eliminado correctamente";

        } else {

         echo  "Error al eliminar el registro selecionado";

    }
    return $id;
}

    function  listar_noticias($conexion){
    ?>
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Autor</th>
        <th>Titulo</th>
        <th>Categoria</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th >Editar</th>
        <th>Eliminar</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias ORDER BY id ASC ";
        $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) 
        {
        ?>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['autor']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['categoria']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['update']; ?></td>
          <td><a href="#">Editar</a></td>
          <td><a href="./elim.php?id=<?php echo $row ['id']; ?>">Eliminar</a></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
    <?php
        }
        ?>
</table>
<?php 

}

function eliminar_noticia($conexion){
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $sql = "DELETE FROM noticias WHERE id = '$id'";
        $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

        if ($resultado) {

         echo "El registro fue eliminado correctamente";

        } else {

         echo  "Error al eliminar el registro selecionado";

    }
    return $id;
}
```

Saludos y gracias a todos de antemano.

PD:2 actualmente se esta ejecutando en un archivo externo a la funcion  que quiero usar.

Comment: Dejo el codigo aqui, por que veo que la pagina hizo algo raro
https://pastebin.com/ZzBskkZE

Comment: La pregunta no termina de quedar clara: ¿A qué te refieres con que una función lleva un href? ¿Qué función estás ejecutando de las que pones (y dónde)? ¿qué funciones quieres ejecutar? Por favor, edítala para clarificar el problema. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y consejos.

Comment: Aparte, y no relacionado con la pregunta directamente: el código que compartes es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL y no debería usarse en entornos de cara al público.

Comment: El tipo de operación que quieres realizar suele hacerse por medio de Ajax, el cual actúa a manera de *puente*  entre el cliente y el servidor. En este caso, recogerías el id desde el cliente y por medio de Ajax enviarías ese dato al servidor para que ejecute el `DELETE` en base a ese id. Además, todo ocurre de forma totalmente transparente al usuario, sin tener que recargar la página y cosas así. Al principio Ajax parece algo difícil, pero no lo es. Conviene que aprendas a usarlo, te facilitará mucho la vida. [Aquí un ejemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6fju-td04). `Run - F9` para probarlo

Comment: El codigo que presentas son funciones php que resuelven las acciones de un CRUD. La pregunta mas bien seria: que archivo php llama a esas funciones? Probablemente desde tu controlador llames a estas funciones. En ese caso, el boton debe apuntar a tu controlador, y que este ejecute la funcion que te interese. No haria falta javascript.

Comment: Crfeo que no me explique, lo dire basico:

Lo que quiero es usar la funcion de eliminar_noticias, en el href de la funcion listar_noticias, referente al tema de seguridad no me precupa, no es una cosa que este  de cara al publico, y solo se puede acceder por el panel de administrador, tambien tengo los directorios protegidos y demas.

Saludos y gracias a todos

Comment: Estoy de acuardo con los dos comentarios anteriores.  Yo lo haria con Ajax.  El Ajax mandaria una llamada al controlador pasando el id de la $row que deseas eliminar, y el controlador seria el encargado de llamar a tu funcion eliminar_noticias()

Comment: aqui tienes ya con un ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540228/href-to-call-a-php-function-and-pass-a-variable

Answer (score 0):

Si mira creo que no fui claro, lo que quiero es ejecutar la función eliminar_noticia en el href, y no se como hacerlo, solo eso. La linea es esta:

```
<td><a href="?$id='<?php echo $row ['id']; ?>'">Eliminar</a></td>
```

y necesito ejecutar esta funcion al pulsar eliminar

```
function eliminar_noticia($conexion, $id){
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM noticias WHERE id = '$id'";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

    if ($resultado) {

     echo "El registro fue eliminado correctamente";

    } else {

     echo  "Error al eliminar el registro selecionado";

}
return $id;
```

}